# Open any file on ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to open files with ionic, for that I use documentViewer ionic, but the problem is that I will not do it, I mean the cell phone has a pdf viewer and I will not open the pdf viewer with the file, but it directs me to play store and tells me to install an application to view pdf. Here I leave my code for that part:

```
this.documentView.viewDocument(url, type, {});
```

As you can see I pass the URL of the file, then the type, and finally nothing, which are the options of documentViewer, Tell me if I'm doing it right or if I should use the other library that is file opener

Answer (score 0):

You can use [In App Browser plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) with the help of google docs if no viewer is installed on the device.

For example :

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }

...

let myUrl = "";
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  myUrl = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
}
this.iab.create(myUrl + url, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=no,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

Comment: Can you detail the functionality and / or give an example? Because I do not know it very well that library

Comment: The file I want to open is inside the device, does it work like this?

Comment: yes you can use local URL (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#local-urls--source-is-in-the-app-package-)

Comment: Thank you, now I try it and I notice

Comment: I get an error 404, the url that I'm passing is like this: file: ///storage/emulated/0/Konecte%20Corp/myarchivo.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[File Opener Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/) works fine. But not all PDF readers support online document view. Try to download pdf with [File Transfer Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/), then open local storiated file.

Comment: I already tried with file opener, but it does not work. It does not detect the reader application for pdf, and what I do is download the file and then I try to open it, also it tells me that it can not find the file